# Omnet veins-lte error

Tags: omnet++

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, sumo 0.22 and omnet 4.6.

While running my veins-lte heterogeneous network after 12 sec I got the    error message below. Is there an error with the sumo coordination from the imported openstreetmap and the ini. playground dimensions? or with the HeterogeneousToLTE.cc file?

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Error message:

```
<!> Error in module (HeterogeneousToLTE) scenario.node[9].
heterogeneousToLTE (id=343) at event #535381, t=12.1: IPvXAddressResolver: module `node[23]' not found.

TRAPPING on the exception above, due to a debug-on-errors=true configuration option. Is your debugger ready?

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0xb7ba2524 in cRuntimeError::breakIntoDebuggerIfRequested (this=0x13fcec60)
    at cexception.cc:296
296            DEBUG_TRAP;
```

Comment: probably the host/vehicle you are trying to reach has left the scenario and its IP can not be resolved... try to inspect it visually in SUMO